# Ошибка компиляции программы C++

Tags: c++

На мой код:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int T;
    cout <<"enter T:"<< endl;
    cin >>T;
    int a, b
        for (int i=0; i<T; i=i+1)
    {
       cout <<"enter a and b:"<< endl;
        cin >>a >>b;
       cout <<"a+b=" <<(a+b)<< endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

выдает ошибку:

> ```
> Compilation error
> main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
> main.cpp:10:9: error: expected initializer before ‘for’
>          for (int i=0; i<T; i=i+1)
>          ^
> main.cpp:10:23: error: ‘i’ was not declared in this scope
>          for (int i=0; i<T; i=i+1)
>                   ^
> ```

Я так понимаю ему не нравится, что `i` нигде не используется. Что делать?

Comment: Вам надо читать ошибки сверху вниз, то есть сперва решить проблему в строке :10:9:, а потом смотреть далее а не наоборот. И помнить то что компилятор часто ругается на строку которая идет после строки с ошибкой, то есть как правило ошибка выше строки :10:9: указанной в данном случае

Answer (score 7):

Забыли точку с запятой.

```
int a, b; //Здесь
```